Azure Storage account Encryption key version is not in sync with Keyvault key version
Azure Storage Account has Customer-managed keys with different version and the key stored in the keyvault is of different version.
Screenshot from storage account provided below.
Storage account screenshot 1
Storage account screenshot 2
Screenshot from the keyvault keys provided below.
Keyvault screenshot
When I am trying to change key with existing key from the keyvault key or generate a new key then I am getting error message - "The operation failed because the specified key vault key '........' was not found."
How do I resolve this error without re-creating the storage account.
Azure Storage Account has Customer-managed keys with different version and the key stored in the keyvault is of different version.
When I am trying to change key with existing key from the keyvault key or generate a new key then I am getting error message - "The operation failed because the specified key vault key '........' was not found."
How do I resolve this error without re-creating the storage account.

try creating a new key in vault that matches with the version of the storage account keys since your requirement is not to recreate the storage account @Izzy

how to create key with matching version ? we can create keys but it wont match the version


Azure Storage account Encryption key version is not in sync with Keyvault key version

The requirement not to recreate the storage account key and to make sync the keys after changing the keys in the storage account was not directly achieved as the key was system assigned and created by azure. This key was fetched when we enabled option customer keys and stored in the key Vault.
Reversing this can't be achieved as the new version key in storage account key version doesn't match with old version key.
In short, it was one way operation when key value was fetched from the storage account vice versa was not possible.
Now follow the steps for matching the version from storage account to keyvault.
Click on change key  under Encryption in storage account

Select new key under keyvault which will make sure key version matches in  both the resources

This new created key version and value matches with the

After creating this new key it looks like this with new version info


Here we can see this version and keys are matching.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-key-vault-hsm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-configure-existing-account?tabs=azure-portal

@Izzy Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
